# Has anyone claimed that no decision is inherently better or more rational than any other decision?

Tags: ethics, metaethics, nihilism, rationality, occams-razor

The [is-ought problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem), for those who believe it is an actual problem, is the problem that you can not deduce an *ought* statement from any number of *is* statements.

It seems natural for this to lead to a more extreme view.

1. Due to Occam's razor, "ought"s simply do not exist.
2. The is-ought problem does not only apply to morality, but also to all rational decision making (i.e. you can not get to the sentence "I ought to survive." or "I ought to be prosperous." or "I ought to pursue pleasure and avoid pain." from is statements), implying by Occam's razor that rational choices do not exist either.
3. That, therefore, any decision is not inherently better or more rational than any other decision. More precisely, the claim that a decision is better or more rational than another decision has no real world meaning, since the terms "rational" as applied to decisions, or "better", have no real world meaning.
4. Even if were to define rational decision in such a way as to avoid this problem (for example, in terms of material facts), rational decision making would still have no [binding force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative_ethics#Binding_force).

This would imply that although given *beliefs* can be rational or irrational, the idea that *decisions* can be rational or irrational is false.

Has any philosopher taken the is-ought problem this far? If so, I imagine that we would be both a moral and existential nihilist.

Comment: 'This is usually used to support the idea that morality is unknowable, and separate from human ideas of morality.' Well, not in Hume. For Hume morality is purely a product of human nature. We can ascertain 'matters of fact', expressible in 'is' statements. Under certain conditions, which Hume specifies, the reaction to a matter of fact will be an emotional reaction which Hume equates with moral judgement about what we 'ought' to do. The nature of morality is perfectly knowable for Hume, and is set out in Treatise, III, and it is a wholly human phenomenon mediated by sympathy and utility.

Comment: No decision... Is a decision.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas Oh, I didn't know that. That being said, I think that it is at least *often* used in that way, even if Hume did not.

Comment: @Richard I assume you mean choosing to do nothing is a decision. In which case, yes, it is. Or perhaps you meant that is impossible to not make decisions (if you decide to not decide, you just made a decision). This is also true.

Comment: Yes :) it's a Japanese proverb. To do nothing... Is an action.

Comment: Could you point to where it is used that way? I suspect it is the same confusion as with Hume. Yes, emotional reactions or some other root oughts are non-rational, but it does not mean that a great deal of rationality is not required for reducing specific decisions to them, or deeming one better than another based on those oughts. That is called means-end analysis. In this regard root ends/oughts are not much different from perceptual facts (which are also non-rational), if you want to logically derive something about reality you better have non-logical premises, like facts, to work from.

Comment: @Conifold. In the Enquiries, more than in the Treatise, Hume emphasised the importance of ascertaining the exact facts, which he took to be not always an easy task, among the preconditions for moral judgement. You probably know this but I add it to refine my own statement. This supports your comment, I am glad to say. Best - GLT.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas Okay, I tried looking it up, but apparently nobody has used the is ought problem to justify moral skepticism. I've removed the offending statement.

Comment: @Conifold the problem is that if you accept Occam's razor and the is-ought problem, then root ends/oughts do not exist, because they are not required to understand reality. On the other hand, perceptual facts are kind of presupposed by Occam's razor. That is, finding an explanation for perceptual facts is the point of Occam's razor.

Comment: There was one philosopher who considered making this argument, but decided not to.

Comment: Being required to understand reality is not a pre-condition of existence, and Occam's razor has nothing to do with perceptual facts specifically. The idea of reducing the man to understanding and reason has been abandoned since pragmatism and existentialism, and the Occam's razor is  "entities are not to be multiplied without necessity", whatever the necessity might be. Since oughts are needed to make decisions and act they exist enough.

Comment: @IMil Which one? (EDIT: Oh wait, that was a joke, wasn't it. :P)

Comment: @PyRulez. Thanks for letting me know. All the best - Geoffrey

Answer (score 1):

We need to avoid confusing our oughts.  There's "ought" on its own, which is what Hume was talking about, and "ought in order to achieve a goal".  If I wish to hear well, I ought to wear my hearing aids.  That doesn't mean I ought to wear my hearing aids.  If I ought to hear well, then I ought to wear my hearing aids.  Therefore, the "ought" doesn't proceed from "is" statements alone, but is either (according to Hume) a non sequitur or based on an existing ought.

This means that it's still possible to make rational decisions, as long as the decision is in a context of knowledge and desired goals.  If I want to hear better, and my hearing aids aren't in my ears, then putting them in is a rational decision.  If I want to hear better, then hitting myself on the head with my phone is not a rational decision (unless I have another goal that that would serve).  Ought I to save more money?  If I want to live a little less well now and have more money later (say, after retirement), then yes.  If I want to enjoy things more while I'm young, then no.  There doesn't have to be a moral context to have a rational decision.

Answer (score 0):

[Sextus Empiricus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextus_Empiricus), following [Pyrrho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhonism), suggests that whenever you can manage to, the right approach to any action is to 'bracket' judgement as to correctness and accept what happens. Obviously this is also a special case of not being attached, and of achieving by being and not doing, so you could consider the Buddhist deduction, and the core of Taoism to offer the same advice in slightly broader forms.

Of course this man was a physician.  So he made decisions all the time.  His traditional epithet implies that he practiced what would now be called 'evidence-based medicine'.  So you can consider this an extreme form of hypocrisy -- except that you should bracket that judgement, and not apply it...

Answer (score -1):

**Is–ought problem is a logical fallacy**

Consider the following problem: a car has a 60 kW engine, so its top speed is 100 mph. If we want a top speed of 130 mph, the engine ought to be at least 100 kW. How do we know what "ought to be" if nobody tried such an engine? The answer would be that we know the laws of physics and we calculated the new top speed from them. The next question would be: how do we know that our model of physical laws describes reality sufficiently? And the answer is: if we know reality through observation to declare what **is**, then we could know reality enough to model what **ought to be** if we had a better engine. Note that we "could" know, that does not guarantee that we would know certainly.

Obviously, we could apply this kind of reasoning to moral problems. For example, a certain percentage of people are stealing because they do not have enough food (a real problem in Hume's time). While humanist philosophers like Rousseau advocated bettering human conditions to cure social ills, i.e. changing the social order to benefit humanity, "evil" philosophers like Hume reverted to skepticism to preserve the status quo.

Since the history of mankind largely repudiates Hume's fallacy by showing that moral betterment of society is possible (i.e. ought to be could be derived from is), we could hold the is–ought problem only as a obsolete sophism, and not as a real problem.

Comment: How do we know what "ought to be" whether anybody tried anything or not? Why should that depend on the quality of the engine? Of course, you already decided that that is what ought to determine it, but that is as circular as proving the parallel postulate by assuming something equivalent to it.  The is/ought problem is in the apparent impossibility of deriving an ought without assuming *any* other ought.

Comment: @Conifold Quality of the car is its speed (simplified of course). Faster car is better, therefore "ought to be" . If you know what is an "essence" of the car, then you know what car ought to be. Similarly, if you know what man is, then you should know what man ought to be. Hume's fallacy is that he assumed that we do not know what (society) ought to be, but we know what (society) is now. This is wrong, because either we do not know anything, or we know what is therefore we could calculate what ought to be.

Comment: @Conifold Consider this: you have a car with certain speed, carrying capacity, safety, reliability, looks, pollution factor ... You know what is, but you decided that this doesn't satisfy your requirements. You need a car that doesn't exist yet, but "ought to be" .

Comment: There is no "essence" to a car or a man, attaching one to them is just an ought by another name. And you apparently haven't read Hume since he had plenty to say as to what a man or society ought to be. He just did not pretend to derive it from facts alone. This said, "this is wrong" derives from an ought as well, your own. Please read up on the [is/ought problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaethics/#IsOOpeQueArg), your current arguments do not even aim at it.

Comment: @Conifold Btw, if we adhere to Hume's worldview no one would invent anything (either car, plane or computer) because all of those things were "ought to be" at certain point of time. But obviously world doesn't care for Hume's sophistry .

Comment: Why? People do things when they are passionate about them, that's what Hume observed, oughts come from passions, or are at least are preceded by them. The only difference between you and him that I can see is that you believe some oughts are objective, while he doubted it. That is called moral realism. You also wish to call objective oughts ises, but that is not the standard terminology that even moral realists use. And, in any case, the issue is purely verbal.

Comment: @Conifold Not entirely true, most of technology improvements were made without much passion, out of business necessity. For example, we need to satisfy government  pollution laws, so we invest in research of various filters and better injectors etc ... They do not exist now, but they ought to exist in our new engine.

Comment: Business necessity, and other sorts of practical necessity, arguably derive from the same source, breaking the laws, or eating too much candy, is bound to lead to unpleasantness eventually, so we defer. But the nature of oughts is an ethical issue separate from the logical issue of whether one can derive an ought from an is.

Comment: @Conifold Again, you are running in circles . You cannot have an "IS" without having a knowledge about system. If you have a car and have its current  pollution level (as numbers) , implicitly you have improved numbers for those same qualities as an "OUGHT TO BE" . Yo cannot have any physical measurement without implicitly knowing that results of that measurement could be different.

Comment: "You cannot have an "IS" without having a knowledge about system" is a tautology. The question is about the source of the ought. "You cannot have any physical measurement without implicitly knowing that results of that measurement could be different"??? Ok, so what?

Comment: @Conifold Let's assume that you have a knowledge that car IS black. That implies that you have the knowledge that car IS NOT blue, green, red or yellow. In your "mind space" , there is automatically more information than what Hume assumed (only things learned by perception) . You automatically have cars of other colors as a potential that didn't yet come to pass. And if your cars has to be let's say circus car, it OUGHT TO BE painted differently, even if such car does not yet exist.

Comment: @Conifold Therefore, source of "ought" is property of the mind to analyze and induce new things from known things , by deriving what "is not" and what "could be" from "is".  Or , contrary to Hume's claims, there is something in the mind that is independent from perception.

Comment: How do you get from different potentials to ought to be X. This sounds like can implies ought, or something like that. Your use of modalities sounds like a mess, which is why it is hard to follow your arguments. In the future express yourself in terms of objective oughts instead of ises, and people will understand you better.

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing. Excellent answer: +1